# How to print HTTP responses in python?

Tags: python, youtube

So I am coding this little simple script that I know will not work, but the script itself is running without errors and making a call to www.googleapis.com, so something is happening there. Without seeing the HTTP response I can't know what is wrong, though. The evidence of it actually doing something is because I am in china, and when I run the interpreter there is a time out until I break the script manually :

```
OUTPUT WITHOUT PROXY :

 File "youtubeconnect.py", line 30, in <module>
    execute()
  File "youtubeconnect.py", line 27, in execute
    youtube = authenticate()
  File "youtubeconnect.py", line 15, in authenticate
    service = build('youtube', 'v3',http=http)
  File "/home/xavier/Code/autotube/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oauth2client-1.5.2-py3.5.egg/oauth2client/util.py", line 140, in positional_wrapper
  File "/home/xavier/Code/autotube/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google_api_python_client-1.4.2-py3.5.egg/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 196, in build
  File "/home/xavier/Code/autotube/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google_api_python_client-1.4.2-py3.5.egg/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 242, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
  File "/home/xavier/Code/autotube/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oauth2client-1.5.2-py3.5.egg/oauth2client/client.py", line 596, in new_request
  File "/home/xavier/Code/autotube/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py3.5.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1314, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/home/xavier/Code/autotube/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py3.5.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1064, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/home/xavier/Code/autotube/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py3.5.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 987, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1229, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 826, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
```

Now, when I run the interpreter through proxychains and tunnel it it works :

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-request| www.googleapis.com 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response| www.googleapis.com is 173.194.208.95
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-173.194.208.95:443-<><>-OK
```

I am new to python, how can get the output of the HTTP error that google is sending me back when I try to connect erroneously to the API ? My code :

```
import httplib2
import os
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenCredentials
#from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
import urllib
def authenticate():
    #scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"
    acc_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    flow = AccessTokenCredentials(
        acc_token,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36')
    http = flow.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = build('youtube', 'v3',http=http)
    return(service)


def initialize_upload(youtube):
    tags = None
    vid = youtube.videos().insert
    media_body = MediaFileUpload('1977.mp4', mimetype='video/mp4',
                                 chunksize=1024 * 1024, resumable=True)


def execute():
    youtube = authenticate()
    initialize_upload(youtube)

execute()
```

Comment: typically with oauth2 it redirects the user to google where the user accepts the scope of the authentication... then it redirects back to the registered www site with a new token that you can use to act on behalf of the user...

Comment: I am using a validated token directly. This is another technique that is not really described on any of the documents of the Google API. I know it is connecting to the api and doing something but I can't see what is going on, and there are not much examples to say none using this technique, but I know it is possible to do it as I have seen reports from other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use logging: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/logging

Also, you can use Fiddler or Wireshark to analyze the packets being sent to you.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have added : `logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
httplib2.debuglevel = 4` But it doesn't print anything ....